# How do I write rotation Operation for the Risc-V(Assembly Language) Do we have any command for it like we have have in 8086?

Tags: assembly, riscv

I have worked with assembly language of 8086 previously, rotation operation in 8086 was just a command. But I can't find a specific keyword for rotation operation in Risc-V assembly language.

Comment: The RISC-V Bitmanip Extension has rotates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like extension "B" should define such an instruction eventually.

Until then you have to compose it using left and right shifts.

Here's an equivalent of the MIPS32R2 rotrv instruction (rotate right by variable count):

```
rotrv:
    subu    neg_count, zero, count
    srlv    tmp1, src, count
    sllv    tmp2, src, neg_count
    or      dst, tmp1, tmp2
```

You can do the same on riscv.

Answer (score 2):

The RISC-V base instruction set doesn't include rotate instructions.

Thus, you have to implement rotation (a.k.a. cyclic shift) with multiple basic instructions e.g.:

```
    .text
    .balign 4
# unsigned long rotl(unsigned long x, unsigned long amnt);
    .global rotl
rotl:
    sll  a2,   a0, a1
    sub  a4, zero, a1
    srl  a3,   a0, a4
    or   a0,   a2, a3
    ret
# unsigned long rotr(unsigned long x, unsigned long amnt);
    .global rotr
rotr:
    srl  a2,   a0, a1
    sub  a4, zero, a1
    sll  a3,   a0, a4
    or   a0,   a2, a3
    ret
```

Note that `sub  a4, zero, a1` wraps around at zero and *shift-left-logical* (`sll`) only uses the lower six (RV64G) or five bits (RV32G) of `a4` as shift amount.

When shifting by an immediate operand, GNU `as` does **not** implicitly truncate the shift-amount, thus one has to explicitly mask it, e.g.:

```
# unsigned long rotl3(unsigned long x);
    .global rotl3
rotl3:
    slli a2, a0,  3
    srli a3, a0, (-3 & 63) # & 31 for RV32G
    or   a0, a2, a3
    ret
# unsigned long rotr3(unsigned long x);
    .global rotr3
rotr3:
    srli a2, a0,  3 
    slli a3, a0, (-3 & 63) # & 31 for RV32G
    or   a0, a2, a3
    ret     
    .global rotl
```

The [RISC-V Bitmanip Extension "B"](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-bitmanip) draft specification does include several additional shift and shuffle instruction including left and right rotate:

> ```
> # RV32, RV64:
> ror   rd, rs1, rs2
> rol   rd, rs1, rs2
> rori  rd, rs1, imm
>
> # RV64 only:
> rorw  rd, rs1, rs2
> rolw  rd, rs1, rs2
> roriw rd, rs1, imm
> ```

([RISV-V Bitmanip Extension V0.92](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-bitmanip), Section 2.2.1, page 14)

Of course, as of 2020, because of the draft status, bitmanip instructions and their encodings may change and support for the "B" extension in software toolchains, simulator and hardware isn't widely available.

Comment: What happens if you don't mask an immediate?  Do you end up with machine code that shifts out all the bits by treating it as a large count?  (x86 for example masks immediate shift counts the same as registers so you don't need to do that.)

Comment: @PeterCordes no, but GNU `as` fails then with: `Error: Improper shift amount (18446744073709551613)`

Comment: Ah, so the problem is that it won't truncate the shift amount to fit into the machine encoding.  Thanks.