# Rotating bits in RISC-V

Tags: bit-manipulation, riscv

Hey so I am kinda new here and to RISC-V.

One of my exercise questions is:

> Rotate right by 4 bits the value of 0x0000000000000123. The expected result is 0x3000000000000012, i.e. all hexadecimal digits move right by one position while the rightmost one moves to the front*

So far, I learned a little bit about the Logical Operations: `andi, or, and xori`. In my previous exercises I learned `add, addi, sub, slli, srli, srai`.

I started off with:

```
addi x6, 0x, 0x123
```

However, I am stuck here. My textbook doesn't really describe things properly so any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest using a bit mask to extract the bits you need to wrap around, and using shifts to accomplish the end goal.

Comment: There's no single instruction to do this, but you can use several to do it.  Consider: how would you accomplish this in C, as C also does not have rotate operators?  If you can solve it in C you can transcribe that to assembly.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Yeah your suggestions helped a lot in my problem. I haven't taken C courses, only learned Java so far. I masked the bits, and shifted it left, shifted the other remaining bits to the right, then added the two registers to my target register.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write rotation Operation for the Risc-V(Assembly Language) Do we have any command for it like we have have in 8086?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55394123/how-do-i-write-rotation-operation-for-the-risc-vassembly-language-do-we-have-a)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
addi x30, x0, 0x123
andi x29, x30, 0x00f //masking all, but the right most hexadecimal digit
slli x6, x29, 60 //shifting this digit all the way to the left (rotating)
srli x7, x30, 4 //shifting the original value 4 bits right
add x5, x6, x7 //adding the two regs
```

Comment: The masking with `andi x29, x30, 0x00f` is superfluous because you shift-left those bits out of the register in the next line, anyways.