# How to do a logical shift with wraparound in RISCV?

Tags: riscv, sll, srl

When doing a shift whether left or right, I want to add back the lost bits with wraparound. How can I do this?

Comment: a wraparound shift is called a [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Circular_shift), and there are no such thing as logical or arithmetic rotations

Comment: duplicates: [Rotating bits in RISC-V](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57949406/995714), [How do I write rotation Operation for the Risc-V(Assembly Language) Do we have any command for it like we have have in 8086?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55394123/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotating bits in RISC-V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57949406/rotating-bits-in-risc-v)

Comment: In short, shift part of the register to the right using `srl`, part of it to the left using `sll` and then combine the result using `or`.

Comment: Try it in C, which doesn't have these as primitive operators.  The approach will be about rhe same.

Comment: Rotation operations were very popular back in the days when processors had few or only one register, so you could shift w/o loosing any bits.  Nowadays with lots of registers, we usually just send the shifted result to a different register if the original value is still needed, instead of rotating.